# SQL Server is not started in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sqlite, ms-sql

I created the local service. My server name is like `sqlitesync.com`. In my database folder created the `configuration (web.config)` and `WCF web service (AuroraSyncService.svc)`. When I test this service in browser it shows nothing.

i followed this tutorial [Link](http://sqlite-sync.com/documentation/installation/)

When start the service http://sqlitesync.com/sqlitesyncservice/AuroraSyncService.svc in browser it shows the empty like [image]

When I create my own (`index.html`) `http://sqlitesync.com/index.html` it works fine

[image: http://sqlitesync.com/index.html]

I don't know how to solve this also I am new to SQL Server.

Anybody provide a solution to solve this..

configuration code:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AuroraSyncCn" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SQLite-Sync.com;User ID=sa;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```